# How to send request body data to 3rd party api using curl in laravel from react component using react query?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, fetch-api, react-query

As fetch api is not working on frontend as it gives cors error, so I am using php curl to make api request.
How we can send post request to php curl api using react query without using fetch in react component.

sample post request with body object -

```
      https://api.example.com/getOperator

      body {'mobile_no' :3489238475}
```

Api route-

```
      Route::post('/offers',
       'App\Http\Controllers\RechargePlansController@getPlan');
```

RechargePlansController.php

```
     class RechargePlansController extends CoreController
    {

    public function getPlan(Request $request){
    $number = $request->mobile_no

     $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.example.com/plans/getDetails',
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
       CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
       CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
       CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{
         'mobile_no': $number
        }"
      ));
    
      $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
      curl_close($curl);
      return $response;
    
}
```

React query useQuery.tsx

```
 export const fetchRechargePlans = async () => {

  API_ENDPOINTS.RECHARGE_PLANS =  'offers';

  const { data } = await http.post(`${url}/${API_ENDPOINTS.RECHARGE_PLANS}`);
  console.log('object',url);
  return data;
  };
  

  export const useRechargePlansQuery = () => {
   return useQuery<Error>( [API_ENDPOINTS.RECHARGE_PLANS], () =>
       fetchRechargePlans()
        );
     };
```

Plans.tsx (Reactjs component)

```
    interface MobileNumber {
    mobile_no: number;
  };
        

   export default function Plans() {

         const[phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('')  ;
         const[data,setData] = useState(null);

        const getOperator = async (data: MobileNumber) => {
        const { data: response } = await 
        http.post(API_ENDPOINTS.RECHARGE_PLANS, 
        data);
        return response;
        };
        
  const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation(getOperator, {

    onSuccess: data => {
      console.log('operator',data);
      const message = "success"
      alert(message)
     },

  onError: () => {
    alert("error")
  },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: MobileNumber) => {
  const operator = {
    ...data
  };
  mutate(operator);
 };

   

  console.log('data',data)

 const handleOnChange = (e: any) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setPhoneNumber(value);
   phoneNumber.length === 10 ? onSubmit(phoneNumber) : null;
};



  return (
         <div className='flex-1 flex-col'> 
            <Input  label='Phone number'
                    type='number'
                    className='rounded'
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                    
            />
        </div>

        )
  }
```